What do you mean by a morphism $Y\sqcup Y\rightarrow Y\times Y$ described by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} id_Y & 0 \\ 0 & id_Y\end{pmatrix} $
I am a newer to homological algebra. Here is one of the definitions of an additive category in my class:
(1) has $0$ object.
(2) has finite products.
(3) has finite coproducts.
(4) The morphism $Y\sqcup Y\rightarrow Y\times Y$ described by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} id_Y & 0 \\ 0 & id_Y\end{pmatrix} $ is an isomorphism.
(5) $\mathrm{Mor}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)$ is an Abelian group.
I am confused with the condition (4). Could anyone please explain this sentence in details? Thanks!

What definitions of coproduct and product are you familiar with?

Whenever a category has a zero object $0$, for every two objects $A,B$ there is a zero map $A\to 0\to B$; in particular, consider $o_Y : Y\to 0 \to Y$. Now, you have two (equivalent) ways to describe a map $Y+Y\to Y\times Y$:

Consider the map $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}o_Y\\id\end{smallmatrix}\right) : Y\to Y\times Y : y\mapsto (0,y)$, and the map $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}id\\o_Y\end{smallmatrix}\right)  : Y\to Y\times Y : y\mapsto (y,0)$. The universal property of coproducts gives a unique map $Y+Y\to Y\times Y$ that acts exactly as the matrix in question.

Consider the map $\big(o_Y\;\; id\big):Y+Y\to Y : in_1(y)=0,in_2(y)=y$, and similarly $\big(id\;\; o_Y\big):Y+Y\to Y : in_2(y)=0,in_1(y)=y$; the universal property of products gives a unique map $Y+Y\to Y\times Y$ that acts exactly as the matrix in question.


You're essentially considering the 2x2 matrix, and splitting it in two rows, or two columns.

In general, the universal properties of coproducts and products imply
$$\begin{align*}\hom(A \sqcup B, C \times D) &\cong \hom(A,C \times D) \times \hom(B, C ,\times D) \\ & \cong \hom(A,C) \times \hom(A,D) \times \hom(B,C) \times \hom(B,D). \end{align*}$$
So these are 4-tuples of morphisms. It is useful to write such a 4-tuple as a matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\hom(A,C) & \hom(B,C) \\ \hom(A,D) & \hom(B,D) \end{pmatrix}$$
The same works for morphisms from any coproduct into any product.
In the case of additive categories, finite coproducts and finite products coincide (at least their underlying objects), and we can also identify the composition of morphisms between finite coproducts as the usual matrix multiplication. This is a very convenient way of handling these morphisms.
Notice that all of this is a direct generalization of the familiar description of linear maps between two standard vector spaces $K^n$ and $K^m$.

A product of two objects $A, B$ is defined as a triple $(A \times B, p_A,p_B)$ consisting of an object $A \times B$ and morphisms $p_A : A \times B \to A, p_B : A \times B \to B$ such that the following universal property is satisfied:

For any two morphism $f_A : X \to A, f_B : X \to B$ there exists a unique morphism $\phi : X \to A \times B$ such that $p_A  \circ \phi = f_A$ and  $p_B  \circ \phi = f_B$.

Denote this morphism by $\phi = \begin{pmatrix} f_A &  f_B \end{pmatrix}$.
Dually, a product of two objects $C, D$ is defined as a triple $(C \sqcup D, i_C,i_D)$ consisting of an object $C \sqcup D$ and morphisms $i_C : C \to C \sqcup D, i_D : D \to C \sqcup D$ such that the following universal property is satisfied:

For any two morphism $g_C : C \to Y, g_D : D \to Y$ there exists a unique morphism $\psi : C \sqcup D \to Y$ such that $\psi \circ i_C  = g_C$ and  $\psi \circ i_C  = g_D$ .

Denote this morphism by $\psi =  \begin{pmatrix} g_C \\ g_D \end{pmatrix}$.
Given four objects $A, B, C, D$ and morphisms $f_{A,C}: A \to C,  f_{A,D}: A \to D, f_{B,C}: B \to C, f_{B,D}: B \to D$, we get two morphisms $\phi = \begin{pmatrix} f_{A,C} &  f_{A,D} \end{pmatrix} : A \to C \times D$ and $\phi' =\begin{pmatrix} f_{B,C} &  f_{B,D} \end{pmatrix} : B \to C \times D$. These induce $\psi = \begin{pmatrix} \phi \\ \phi' \end{pmatrix} : A \sqcup B \to C \times D$ which is written as
$$\psi = \begin{pmatrix} f_{A,C} & f_{A,D} \\ f_{B,C} & f_{B,D} \end{pmatrix} .$$
Apply this to $A = B = C= D = Y$ and $f_{A,C} = f_{B,D} = id_Y$ and $f_{A,D} = f_{B,C} = 0$.
